# Passing a Method with Out String Parameters c#

Tags: c#

Currently i'm trying to call a method inside of my Create button click, and one of the parameters in that method is an out string and I was wondering how to pass the "out string solutionUniqueName" parameter without it throwing an error.

Here's part of the method i'm trying to use.

```
public static Entity createSolution(IOrganizationService _serviceProxy, out string solutionUniqueName)
    {
        Entity solutionToReturn = null;

        solutionUniqueName = "CreatedSolution_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_');

        //Check whether it already exists
        QueryExpression queryCheckForSampleSolution = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "solution",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression()
        };
```

And here is the button click that i'm trying to call it in.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String sourceOrgName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceOrgName"];
        String targetOrgName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetOrgName"];

        CRMConnector CRMConnector = new CRMConnector(sourceOrgName, targetOrgName);

        CRMConnection sourceConnection = CRMConnector.CRMConnections.Where(p => p.isSource == true).FirstOrDefault();
        CRMConnection targetConnection = CRMConnector.CRMConnections.Where(p => p.isTarget == true).FirstOrDefault();

        Entity createEntitySolutions = SolutionActions.createSolution(sourceConnection._orgService, out string solutionUniqueName);
```

Where i'm receiving the error is with the out string SolutionUniqueName on the last line.
The error that i'm getting is CS0103 - The name 'solutionUniqueName' does not exist in the current context
and CS1525 - invalid expression term 'string'

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error, and what version of C#?

Comment: You forgot to post the error message. What does the error tell you? The syntax you use is C#7, do you use the correct compiler?

Comment: I don't see CS0103 - are you sure you don't have a version that uses `.createSolution(sourceConnection._orgService, out solutionUniqueName);` (i.e. no `string`, which is the bit that declares the variable)

Comment: I had tried doing just "out solutionUniqueName" before but it didn't work. After adding the String solutionUniqueName; above it then it worked correctly with the "out solutionUniqueName". Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String solutionUniqueName; // create your out string variable

        String sourceOrgName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceOrgName"];
        String targetOrgName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetOrgName"];

        CRMConnector CRMConnector = new CRMConnector(sourceOrgName, targetOrgName);

        CRMConnection sourceConnection = CRMConnector.CRMConnections.Where(p => p.isSource == true).FirstOrDefault();
        CRMConnection targetConnection = CRMConnector.CRMConnections.Where(p => p.isTarget == true).FirstOrDefault();

        Entity createEntitySolutions = SolutionActions.createSolution(sourceConnection._orgService, out solutionUniqueName); //after the function call, solutionUniqueName conserves its value from the method
```

Comment: if I put "out solutionUniqueName);" it works. Thank you!

Comment: Ok. I editted the answer to include out. Happy coding